# python - Retrieve and save links from webpage but only one per domain

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urlparse

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to save the links from a website into a list without repeating urls with same domain

Example:
`www.python.org/download`  and  `www.python.org/about`

should only save the first one ([www.python.org/download](http://www.python.org/download))  and not repeat it later

**This is what i've got so far**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request"
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
atag = doc.find_all('a', href=True)
links = []
#below should be some kind of for loop
```

Comment: Yes, you will need a for loop which parses the domain from the full URL then checks if you already have that domain. The last part can be made easier by using a `set` instead of a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner:

```
links = {nl for a in doc.find_all('a', href=True) if (nl := urlparse(a["href"]).netloc) != ""}
```

Explained:

```
links = set()  # define empty set
for a in doc.find_all('a', href=True):  # loop over every <a> element
    nl = urlparse(a["href"]).netloc  # get netloc from url
    if nl:
        links.add(nl)  # add to set if exists
```

output:

```
{'www.w3.org', 'datatracker.ietf.org', 'www.python.org', 'requests.readthedocs.io', 'github.com', 'www.sphinx-doc.org'}
```

Comment: This is a great solution but i forgot to be more clear with the result i wanted, edited the example on the original post to be more concise, but basically i want to keep the entire url   but one per domain, sorry for the misunderstanding